GLSL Shader: Unexpected Behavior in Pixel Looping
I'm working on a GLSL shader and encountering an issue when looping over pixels using a while loop. The same code works fine on desktop devices but produces different results on mobile devices (both Android and iOS).
The same logic produces inconsistent effects on desktop and mobile devices.
results image
I'm trying to add an effect within the texture area, but it seems to produce different results.


(function() {
  "use strict";
  var scene;
  var renderer;
  var camera;
  var uniforms;
  var material;

  const screenSize = {
    desk: {
      w: 640,
      h: 480
    },
    mob: {
      w: 240,
      h: 320
    },
  };
  async function loadTexture(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
      loader.load(
        url,
        (texture) => resolve(texture), // Resolve with the loaded texture
        undefined, // Progress callback, if needed
        (error) => reject(error) // Reject on error
      );
    });
  }

  async function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("three-canvas");
    // Initialize WebGL Renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas
    });
    // renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    const size = screen.width < 600 ? screenSize.mob : screenSize.desk;
    renderer.setSize(size.w, size.h);

    // Initialize Scenes
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Initialize Camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      45,
      //   window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      size.w / size.h,
      1,
      100
    );
    camera.position.z = 10;

    // Create Light
    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(0, 0, 500);
    scene.add(light);

    // Create Ball
    var vertShader = document.getElementById("vertexShader").innerHTML;
    var fragShader = document.getElementById("fragmentShader").innerHTML;

    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(8, 8);
    const texture = await loadTexture("https://camweara-customers.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Teststore/test.png");
    console.log("texture: ", texture);

    uniforms = {
      texture1: {
        type: "t",
        value: texture
      },
      // mouse: { type: 'v2', value: new THREE.Vector2(0.0, 0.0) }
    };
    console.log("uniforms: ", uniforms);

    // Create a shader material
    material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      vertexShader: vertShader,
      fragmentShader: fragShader,
      uniforms: uniforms,
      transparent: true,
    });

    // Create the plane mesh
    const plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(plane);
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    init();
    animate();
  };
})();
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.160.0/three.min.js">
  </script>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      background: #1d1d1d;
    }
    
    canvas {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="three-canvas"></canvas>

    <script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
      varying vec2 vUv;

      void main() {
          vUv = uv;
          gl_Position =   projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
      }
    </script>

    <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
      precision highp float;

      uniform sampler2D texture1;
      varying vec2 vUv;

      void main() {
          vec4 bg_clr = texture2D(texture1, vUv);
          vec4 finalClr = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);

          float pixelStep = 0.001;
          vec4 finalX;
          vec4 finalY;

          if(bg_clr.w > 0.2){
            float i = 0.0;
            while(i < 1.0){
                vec2 pos = vUv - vec2(i, 0.0);
                vec4 xColor = texture2D(texture1, pos);
                if(xColor.w < 0.01){
                    finalX = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
                    break;
                }
                i = i + pixelStep;
            }
            i=0.0;
            while(i < 1.0){
                vec2 pos = vUv + vec2(0.0, i);
                vec4 xColor = texture2D(texture1, pos);
                if(xColor.w < 0.1){
                    finalY = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
                    break;
                }
                i = i + pixelStep;
            }
            finalClr = mix(finalX,finalY,0.5);
          }

          gl_FragColor = finalClr;
      }
    </script>
</body>

</html>




On laptop I see something between from your image... and iOS I see something around 1/4 of that...

Please add some details on your mobile device! Tested it with Firefox on Android and got the green heart without rastering issue. There is only the difference in padding.

I'm not sure what caused your problem, but I have some ideas, and hopefully, some of them will help you.
First, mobile drivers are known as unreliable and sometimes don't follow the specification.
If your hardware, browser, or driver is old, it may not support WebGL 2, and Three.js fallbacks to WebGL 1. In WebGL 1, supporting highp is not mandatory in the fragment shader. So when you declare precision highp float; you might cause undefined behavior. You can check those things in renderer.capabilities.isWebGL2, and in renderer.capabilities.precision.
Apart from this, I don't see any undefined behavior. You sample the texture outside of the (0-1) interval, which shouldn't be a problem, but it's mobile, so who knows?
However, what I can see is that your code is very unusual. You use while, if, and break in the shader to jump to other parts of the code. Since in different fragment shader invocations, the loop exits at different times, this will cause shader divergence, forcing the GPU to execute your code more or less in a serial way, instead of using its many cores which defeats the purpose of GPUs. Also, you potentially sample a texture 2000 times in a single fragment shader invocation. And you can have millions of fragment shader invocations in a frame. It's a ton of texture sampling which is one of the most performance-heavy operations. This can be very slow. For smaller textures, caching might save you, but in bigger textures, it's very slow.
I'm not sure what is the desired result you want to achieve, but if you want to color pixels below a certain alpha threshold with a color, and color the ones above, with another color, then it can be greatly simplified:
void main() {
  vec4 bg_clr = texture2D(texture1, vUv);
  gl_FragColor = mix(vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), vec4(0.5,0.5,0.0,1.0), bvec4(bg_clr.w > 0.2));
}

